# In C programming how to use the value of an array outside the function where the value of the array is assigned?

Tags: function

In my program I used a function called

```
void printBoard(char board[26][26], int n);
```

This is my actual coding:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void printBoard(char board[26][26], int n);

int main(void) {
    //variable 'n' determines board dimension
    int n;
    printf("Enter the board dimension: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char board[n][n];
    printBoard(board, n);
    printf("\n\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%c",board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void printBoard(char board[26][26], int n){
    printf("  ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%c",97+i);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            board[i][j]='U';
        }
    }
    board[(n/2)-1][(n/2)-1]='W';
    board[n/2][n/2]='W';
    board[(n/2)-1][n/2]='B';
    board[n/2][(n/2)-1]='B';
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%c ",97+i);
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%c",board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The value of the array 'board[26][]26' gets assigned inside the function 'printBoard'. So the value gets lost once I am outside of the scope of this function. But I need to use the value of this array outside of this function. How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: If the function changes the values of the board array, it should persist outside the function because it's modifying the actual memory in the array.  Is it not doing so?  If not, please post more code.

Comment: I added my actual function in the question above @kcraigie

Comment: yes, i would expect that to actually change the contents of the array passed in such that the array would contain the new values after the function has returned

Comment: How to get those value back? @kcraigie

Comment: simply access the array outside the function as if you had modified the array in the calling code

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the array into `printBoard` by value, you're just passing a pointer.  The changes in the function will persist beyond the function because you're modifying the same memory, not a copy.  If you're seeing unexpected output, it's not because of a scope issue with changes made by `printBoard`.

Comment: No the value gets vanished outside of the function.

Comment: Please try to explain with a little more technical accuracy than "gets vanished."  If it literally gets vanished, then you're dealing with an act of god and SO can't help you.  If you don't know more details, set a break point, step through with the debugger, verify what you're accessing, what its values are, and when those values change.

Comment: I just added my main coding, please have a look what am I getting wrong here? @Spagpants

Comment: Thanks I fixed it @Spagpants